# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated returning false

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm building an ASP.NET Core 3.0 application and I am having trouble with the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property. It always returns `false`, despite the fact that I have an ASP.NET Core Identity cookie in the browser (sign-in just finished successfully). Here are the pieces of my code in the `Startup` class:

```cs
services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(options =>
{
    options.Password = new PasswordOptions()
    {
        RequireDigit = true,
        RequiredLength = 6,
        RequireLowercase = false,
        RequireUppercase = false,
        RequireNonAlphanumeric = false
    };
    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = false;
})
  .AddEntityFrameworkStores<AmitDbContext>()
  .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

And I added this in the `Configure` method:

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();
```

I've tried to delete `AddAuthentication()`, delete `UseAuthentication()`, as well as other combinations with this options, but the property still returns `false` :(.

Please help me.

Comment: It's **authentication** - neither "authentification" nor "authenfication" ....

Comment: marc_s, i'm sorry, i'm very nervous now...Hope you will understand

Comment: Did you put `app.UseAuthentication` after `app.UseRouting()` and before `app.UseEndpoints` ?

Comment: jandrew, nope, should I?

Comment: Try adding `.AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options => Configuration.Bind("CookieSettings", options));` to the end of your `services.AddAuthentication(options => { ... })` call. Just chain it on to the end after the parameters. Here's a link to the docs that should clarify it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: And yes the order of the `app.UseAuthentication()` is very important in your `Configure` method. Make sure it's in the right place. The docs I linked should be able to clarify what you need.

Comment: Add your controller code so we can see what is going on.